# What Ubuntu Phone Apps are there?

Tags: youtube, twitter

What kinds of apps are in the Ubuntu store?
Can you get facebook, pintrest, twitter, Youtube etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to uappexplorer.com.
Here you find them all. You can even wish for new apps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/505858)

Comment: @JensErat  I'm not sure how that would work -- it's a directory of apps.  This is like asking for a summary of a phone book.